# Why use yup validation?

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

There is a validation method provided by the react hook form. Nevertheless, some developers sometimes use yup validation. What I thought about seems to have the advantage of using schema validation together in the frontend and backend.
I wonder if there is anything else out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using zod as an external validation instead of yup ...

> schema validation together in the frontend and backend.

Another big advantage is ...

- Since the schema can be defined independently, unit testing can be done easily.
- Since the schema can be defined independently, it is easy to understand as a validation definition.
- Can handle **complex validation**

Complex validation is, for example, "when the validation of field A depends on the state of other fields B".

With `zod`, you can create complex validations across other fields, such as with　`refine` `superRefine`.

- https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#refine
- https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#superrefine